# I can't seem to insert a node in a tree. Can someone take a look at my code and tell me where did I do wrong?

Tags: c, data-structures, file-processing

I've been trying to insert a node to my tree through file processing but it only always inserts one node then the program will force close itself. I have tried to put the data on a linkedlist and it worked. So probably the problem here is not the file.txt itself but my tree. Can someone tell me where did i do wrong?

Here is my tree algorithm

```
struct user {
    char username[50];
    int money;
    char favorite[50];
    user *left;
    user *right;
};

user *root = NULL;

user *userTree(char username[], int money, char favorite[]) {
    user *newBranch = (user *) malloc(sizeof(user));
    strcpy(newBranch->favorite, favorite);
    strcpy(newBranch->username, username);
    newBranch->money = money;
    return newBranch;
}

user *insertUser(user *root,char username[], int money, char favorite[]) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return userTree(username ,money, favorite);
    }
    else if (strcmp(username, root->username) < 0) {
        root->left = insertUser(root->left, username, money, favorite);
    }
    else {
        root->right = insertUser(root->right, username, money, favorite);
    }
    return root;
}
```

Here is my file processing algorithm

```
void insertCredential() {
    FILE* fr = fopen("users/users.txt", "r");
    while (!feof(fr)) {
        char username[50], garbage[50], favorite[50];
        int money;
        fscanf(fr, "%[^#]#%[^#]#%d#%[^\n]\n", username, garbage, &money, favorite);
        root = insertUser(root, username, money, favorite);
        puts("test insert");
    }
    fclose(fr);
}
```

I have tried to put the data in a linked list and it worked but I want to know exactly why can't I insert it on a tree

Comment: There are some indicators that you're not programming C, but rather **C++**. Like being able to use the structure name `user` without the `struct` keyword. Or the need to cast the result of `malloc` (which you [shouldn't do in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858)).

Comment: Your code doesn't initialise `left` and `right` members after `malloc()`, leading to undefined behavior.

Comment: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471)

Comment: Are you using a C or a C++ compiler?

Comment: @trincot yeah it works after I initialize the left and right to be NULL, thank you so much!

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I use a c compiler

Comment: That code, as shown, should not build as plain C. That means you're either build it as C++ (is the source files named something ending in `.cpp` or `.cc` or similar?) or it's not a proper [mre].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, the file itself ends with .cpp

Comment: Then it's built as a C++ source file. If you are studying C then you're not learning it correctly. A plain C source file should have the ending `.c`.

Comment: Arigatod, Tip: useful to also post sample data used for input as well as output seen and output expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least these problems:

1. [code doesn't initialise left and right members after malloc(), leading to undefined behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74420656/i-cant-seem-to-insert-a-node-in-a-tree-can-someone-take-a-look-at-my-code-and#comment131376832_74420656).  Consider `calloc()`. @trincot
2. `while (!feof(fr))` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74420656/i-cant-seem-to-insert-a-node-in-a-tree-can-someone-take-a-look-at-my-code-and#comment131376883_74420656).  @Andreas Wenzel.  Check return value of `fscanf()`.
3. `"%[^#]#%[^#]#%d#%[^\n]\n"` lacks widths allowing input overruns.  Add widths.  `"%49[^#]#%49[^#]#%d#%49[^\n]\n"`
4. Result of `fopen()` not checked.
5. Allocation retuned pointer not checked for success.
6. Code is not valid C.  Looks like a C++ compiler used: `user *root = NULL;` --> `struct user *root = NULL;`. @Some programmer dude

Weaknesses:

10. `money` as an `int` may be too narrow.  Consider `long` and a *width*: `"%d"` --> `"%9ld"`.
11. Cast not needed in `newBranch = (user *) malloc(sizeof(user));` in C.  Easier to maintain when the size referenced the object and not the type: `newBranch = malloc(sizeof newBranch[0]);`
12. Greater applicability to use `const` for unchanged reference data: `userTree(char username[], int money, char favorite[])` --> `userTree(const char username[], int money, const char favorite[])`.
13. Trailing `"\n"` can read multiples white-spaces.  Better error checking to use `fgets()` to read 1 *line* of line oriented data and then parse.

Comment: Note that even with `"%49[^#]#%49[^#]#%d#%49[^\n]\n"`, you can still trigger undefined behavior with the `%d`.  The only reliable format string must also limit `%d`, but the best way to use `scanf` is to toss it in the bin.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Agree about `"%d"` and `scanf()`.  See updated #10.